# FullCalendar showing Duplicates Events on Month change

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, visualforce, apex

I am working on adding events to fullcalendar with Javascript. I am using fullcalendar-2.7.2. The events are added when i click on the custom button but when I change the month it shows many duplicate events.
Here is the code that I have written :-

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({                   
            theme: true,
            eventClick: function(event) {
                // opens events in a popup window
                window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
                return false;
            },
            loading: function(bool) {
                $('#processingDiv').toggle(bool);
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                var eventData;
                if (title) {
                    eventData = {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end
                };
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
            }
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        defaultDate: moment().utc().valueOf(),
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            fixedWeekCount: false
        });
        try {
            //This data is showing Okay. This one is the Test Event in image Below on Date 1.
            var jsonStart = JSON.parse('{!jsonStringSF}');
            var myCalendar = $('#calendar'); 
            for(var i=0; i < jsonStart.length; i++) {
                var myEvent = {
                  id: jsonStart[i].id,
                  title: jsonStart[i].title,
                  allDay: jsonStart[i].allDay,
                  start: jsonStart[i].startDate,
                  end: jsonStart[i].endDate
            };
            myCalendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', myEvent.id );
            myCalendar.fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', myEvent, true );
                    }
        } catch(err) {
            alert(err.message);
        }

    });
</script>
<body>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="getEventsFromGoogle" action="{!getEventsFromCalendar}" onComplete="showEventsOnCalendar('{!jsonString}');" />
        <apex:actionFunction name="syncEventsToGoogle" action="{!startSyncToGoogle}" onComplete="hideProcessingDiv();" />
    </apex:form>
    <div id="processingDiv" style="display:none;"> 
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block"/> 
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block"> 
            <img src="/img/loading24.gif" style="vertical-align:middle; horizontal-align:middle"/> 
            <span>Please wait...</span> 
        </apex:outputPanel> 
    </div>
    <div id="allButtons">
        <button class="ui-button ui-state-default" onClick="syncToGoogle();">Sync Salesforce to Google</button>
        <button class="ui-button ui-state-default" onclick="connectToGoogle();">Sync Google to Salesforce</button>
    </div>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
<script>
    function syncToGoogle() {
        showProcessingDiv();
        syncEventsToGoogle();
    }
    function connectToGoogle() {
        showProcessingDiv();
        getEventsFromGoogle();
    }
function showEventsOnCalendar(jsonString) {
//jsonString is [{"title":"Assign Task","startDate":"2016-05-07T13:00:00+05:30","sequence":1,"recurrence":["RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=SU,SA"],"id":"mhpufelkfo1d7thn2naqm2s2ec","endDate":"2016-05-07T14:00:00+05:30","allDay":false}]
try {

    var json = JSON.parse(jsonString); //This is String which has list of events.

    var myCalendar = $('#calendar'); 

    var myEvent = '';

    for(var i=0; i < 1; i++) { //For testing I have itrated the loop just once.

        myEvent = '';

        var recurValue = JSON.stringify(json[i].recurrence);

        //RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20160520T110000Z;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SU,SA
        //Recurrence returns this format.

        if(recurValue != null && recurValue != 'null') {
            var Frequency = recurValue.match("FREQ=(.*?);");
            var Until = recurValue.match("UNTIL=(.*?);");
            var ByDay = recurValue.match("BYDAY=(.*?)\"]");
            if(ByDay[1] == null && ByDay[1] == 'null') {
                ByDay[1] = '';
            }
            var repeatDays = [];
            if(ByDay[1].indexOf('MO') > -1) {
                repeatDays.push(1);
            }
            if(ByDay[1].indexOf('TU') > -1) {
                repeatDays.push(2);
            }
            if(ByDay[1].indexOf('WE') > -1) {
                repeatDays.push(3);
            }
            if(ByDay[1].indexOf('TH') > -1) {
                repeatDays.push(4);
            }
            if(ByDay[1].indexOf('FR') > -1) {
                repeatDays.push(5);
            }
            if(ByDay[1].indexOf('SA') > -1) {
                repeatDays.push(6);
            }
            if(ByDay[1].indexOf('SU') > -1) {
                repeatDays.push(0);
            }
            myEvent = {
                id: json[i].id,
                title: json[i].title,
                allDay: json[i].allDay,
                start: json[i].startDate,
                end: json[i].endDate,
                dow: repeatDays
            };
        } else {
            myEvent = {
            id: json[i].id,
            title: json[i].title,
            allDay: json[i].allDay,
            start: json[i].startDate,
            end: json[i].endDate
        };
    }
        $('.fc-event').remove(); //Tried this is solve the problem but failed.
        //myCalendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', myEvent.id ); //also tried this but still no luck.
        myCalendar.fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', myEvent, true );
    }
    hideProcessingDiv();
} catch(err) {
    hideProcessingDiv();
    alert(err.message);
}
}
```

This is how it looks at start :-
[image]

Here is the screenshot of the problem when click on the next month or come back: -
[image]

Can anyone suggest me the solution to stop the duplicates?

Comment: mm.. seems complicated, :(

Comment: You are probably call this function every time you change the month. Can you share the rest of the code? Best to add a jsFiddle

Comment: this function is on onclick of a button above the calendar. it is not a part of the calendar. So no chance this function is called multiple times. It is calendar's 'renderEvent' which is causing the problem i guess.

Comment: You are not showing enough of your code to know what is happening. This also looks unnecessary as fullcalendar provides a method to [grab events as a json feed](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/). Also have a look at [viewRender](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/), [destroy](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/destroy/) and [viewDestroy](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewDestroy/) they might be helpful as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks guys for the reply. Now I have updated my whole code. Please help me around.

Comment: Without seeing more of the code its difficult to tell. But my best guess is that events are being pushed to repeatDays on every click. Try using console.log(repeatDays) to see whats going on with it